# Is there a way to have an Implacable Ranger not have to move after a kill?

Tags: xcom-2

Implacable is a Scout Ranger ability that gives them a single bonus move for the turn after making a kill during that turn.

**Is there a way to have your ranger stay in his/her current location when Implacable activates, instead of moving to a new tile?** I always seem to be forced to move to a new tile instead of staying in place, which is annoying because oftentimes the current tile is the best one for my ranger.

Maybe I'm just not using Implacable rangers correctly? Maybe I should have them make kills out of cover first, before ducking into cover tiles?

Comment: Backspace can be used to end your turn. I haven't tried that with a ranger because mine never live long enough to level that high, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are sure you moved all your other soldiers and only the ranger(s) with their bonus move remain, click the "end turn" button. It's the one with the "X" in the upper right corner (hotkey: <kbd>End</kbd>).

Moving the ranger as close as possible to the target and relying on the Implacable bonus move to bring them into cover is risky. Remember that you only get the move when the ranger *kills* their target. When the target survives against all odds, the ranger might end up in a very vulnerable position. So you should avoid doing this unless you have a plan B for eliminating the target this turn (and any other opponents which would then have an easy shot on your ranger). Instead have your ranger attack from a reasonably protected position and if they are successful, use the bonus move to bring them into an even more secure one.

Comment: Backspace also works as a hotkey.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this on console?

Answer (score 0):

If during implacable you press a number key and it prevents you ending turn, in the very top right of the screen there is a button that says "back to movement" click it and then you can press backspace to end the current turn.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, without ending your turn. Just click on the Ranger's current tile and (I assume) it sets the current location as the destination and ends his/her free move.